# Escribir ruta de archivo xml dentro de app.config en c#

Tags: c#, xml, archivo, app.config

Este es mi primer foro en esta plataforma y quisera preguntar lo siguiete:

Se puede escribir o especificar la ruta de un archivo xml dentro del app.config en c#, de modo que cuando yo lea un archivo con una función o método solo tenga que colocar el nombre del archivo y nada mas, y no escribir la ruta del archivo.

Si me pueden asesorar. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Intentaste hacer algo? como leer el xml por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Ruta donde se va a guardar-->
    <add key="SavePath" value="D:\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Spalding\ReporteSpaldingConsole\SaveFiles"></add>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Y para leerlo

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("SavePath")]
```

Tienes que agregar la referencia System.Configuration

Lo puedes usar asi:

```
string directorio = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("SavePath")];
XmlDocument listaParametros = new XmlDocument();
listaParametros.Load($@"{directorio}\ParametrosCfdi.xml");
```

O asi

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Ruta donde se va a guardar-->
    <add key="SavePath" value="D:\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Spalding\ReporteSpaldingConsole\SaveFiles\ParametrosCfdi.xml"></add>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>


string archivo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("SavePath")];
XmlDocument listaParametros = new XmlDocument();
listaParametros.Load(archivo);
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, aqui no aparece el código, ponlo como parte de tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder. Tengo otra duda: Tengo que poner este código primero: 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("SavePath")];   


Y a continuación puedo usar estas líneas de códigos para que me lea el archivo xml, y ya funciona.
XmlDocument listaParametros = new XmlDocument();
listaParametros.Load(new XmlTextReader("ParametrosCfdi.xml"));

O falta hacer algo más para que vincule el archivo xml con la ruta?

Esperando otra respuesta. Como siempre gracias,

Comment: Hola agregue contenido a la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Entonces veo que no basta con colocar solo el nombre del archivo ParametrosCfdi.xml,   sino tambien hay que agregar una variable que sería la ruta con el @ adelante y las llaves.  Yo pensé que ya solo bastaba colocar el nombre del archivo solamente.  Estonces este ultimo es imposible colocar el nombre del archivo solamente?

Comment: Si solo vas a leer de ese archivo lo puedes poner la ruta completa en el archivo de configuracion

Comment: Disculpa no entiendo. Tengo solo un arhivo para leer. En la archivo de configuración en <appSettings>  ya colocaste una ruta larga.  Adonde entonces poner otra vez la ruta?.  Decis que incluya en la ruta del app.config el nombre del archivo xml?

Comment: Lo que te entiendo es que quieres tener la ruta completa del archivo en la configuración no?  paa que solo tengas que usar ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("SavePath")] para crear tu XmlDoc

Comment: Si ahora. Eso queria. Incluiste el nombre del archivo xml en la ruta del <appSettings> del app.config.  Y despues referenciaste la variable archivo que contiene todo la ruta y el nombre del archivo xml en el método listaParametros.Load(archivo).   Si eso me sirve.  Muchas gracias por ayudarme. Saludos.